# In Laravel, why can I not assign values to an Eloquent Model directly from an array?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This isn't causing any problems, I'm just totally confused by some behaviour I'm running into so would appreciate some insight.

In my Laravel application I hit an API and loop through it like so:

```
$response = Http::get('https://example.com/api');
$articles = $response->json();

foreach($articles as $article){
    // do stuff
}
```

Within the loop I then use an Eloquent model to persist some data to my database. The thing that's totally confusing me though is that if do this, it works fine:

```
$article_permalink = $article['permalink'];
$article_headline = $article['headline'];

$article = new Article;
$article->permalink = $article_permalink;
$article->headline = $article_headline;
$article->save();
```

Whereas if I just assign the values directly from my array, it doesn't work, and I receive the error below:

```
$article = new Article;
$article->permalink = $article['permalink'];
$article->headline = $article['headline'];
$article->save();
```

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'permalink' cannot be null
```

I receive the above error for both fields. These values *absolutely are* defined in all cases, and it works flawlessly simply by first assigning the array version of variable to a standard variable before insertion. What could I be missing?

Thanks

Comment: You are overwriting your `$article` variable with the model intialization, hence `$article` is no longer an array but on empty Article Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `$article` variable. So when you assign your model attributes `$article` is no longer an array but an empty Article Model Object.

Try this:

```
$articleModel = new Article;
$articleModel->permalink = $article['permalink'];
$articleModel->headline = $article['headline'];
$articleModel->save();
```

Alternatively, changes your loop to:

```
foreach($articles as $articleArray){
    $article = new Article;
    $article->permalink = $articleArray['permalink'];
    $article->headline = $articleArray['headline'];
    $article->save();
}
```

Comment: Haha, of course.  So nothing to do with Laravel or Eloquent, just me being a fool! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

On your model: permalink and headline should be fillable:

```php
class Atricle extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'permalink',
        'headline',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I believe this is to allow mass assignment, but that's not what was going on here.